# PostgreSQL Exception Handling

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am new to PostgreSQL. Could anybody please correct this query.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN;
    CREATE TABLE "Logs"."Events"
    (
        EventId BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        PrimaryKeyId bigint NOT NULL,
        EventDateTime date NOT NULL DEFAULT(now()),
        Action varchar(12) NOT NULL,
        UserId integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "Office"."Users"(UserId),
        PrincipalUserId varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT(user)
    );

    CREATE TABLE "Logs"."EventDetails"
    (
        EventDetailId BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        EventId bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES "Logs"."Events"(EventId),
        Resource varchar(64) NOT NULL,
        OldVal varchar(4000) NOT NULL,
        NewVal varchar(4000) NOT NULL
    );


    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Task completed sucessfully.'
EXCEPTION;
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    RAISE ERROR @ErrorMessage, @LineNumber, @ErrorState --how to catch errors and display them????
END;
```

Questions:

1. How to print a message like 'PRINT' in T-SQL?
2. How to raise errors with exception information?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

To catch the error message and its code:

```
do $$       
begin

    create table yyy(a int);
    create table yyy(a int); -- this will cause an error

exception when others then 

    raise notice 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. '
                 'Transaction was rolled back';

    raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;

end; $$ 
language 'plpgsql';
```

Haven't found the line number yet

**UPDATE April, 16, 2019**

As suggested by Diego Scaravaggi, for Postgres 9.2 and up, use [GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS](https://www.depesz.com/2011/07/20/waiting-for-9-2-stacked-diagnostics-in-plpgsql/):

```
do language plpgsql $$
declare
    v_state   TEXT;
    v_msg     TEXT;
    v_detail  TEXT;
    v_hint    TEXT;
    v_context TEXT;
begin

    create table yyy(a int);
    create table yyy(a int); -- this will cause an error

exception when others then 

    get stacked diagnostics
        v_state   = returned_sqlstate,
        v_msg     = message_text,
        v_detail  = pg_exception_detail,
        v_hint    = pg_exception_hint,
        v_context = pg_exception_context;

    raise notice E'Got exception:
        state  : %
        message: %
        detail : %
        hint   : %
        context: %', v_state, v_msg, v_detail, v_hint, v_context;

    raise notice E'Got exception:
        SQLSTATE: % 
        SQLERRM: %', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM;     

    raise notice '%', message_text; -- invalid. message_text is contextual to GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS only

end; $$;
```

Result:

```
NOTICE:  Got exception:
        state  : 42P07
        message: relation "yyy" already exists
        detail : 
        hint   : 
        context: SQL statement "create table yyy(a int)"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 11 at SQL statement
NOTICE:  Got exception:
        SQLSTATE: 42P07 
        SQLERRM: relation "yyy" already exists

ERROR:  column "message_text" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT message_text
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT message_text
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 33 at RAISE
SQL state: 42703
```

Aside from `GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS` is SQL standard-compliant, its diagnostics variables (e.g., `message_text`) are contextual to GSD only. So if you have a field named `message_text` in your table, there's no chance that GSD can interfere with your field's value.

Still no line number though.

Comment: Would postgres issue a rollback automatically if one statement fails? Is it unnecessary to explicitly roll it back?

Comment: Yes.  If you are in a transaction (after 'begin' but before 'commit' or 'rollback') and an error occurs then everything since the 'begin' is rolled back.

Comment: How would one take `raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;` and get this data into a table of sorts

Comment: since 9.2 edition 
GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS myVariable = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
It is very useful.

Answer (score 18):

Use the [DO statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html), a new option in version 9.0:

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql
$$
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE "Logs"."Events"
    (
        EventId BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        PrimaryKeyId bigint NOT NULL,
        EventDateTime date NOT NULL DEFAULT(now()),
        Action varchar(12) NOT NULL,
        UserId integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "Office"."Users"(UserId),
        PrincipalUserId varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT(user)
    );

    CREATE TABLE "Logs"."EventDetails"
    (
        EventDetailId BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        EventId bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES "Logs"."Events"(EventId),
        Resource varchar(64) NOT NULL,
        OldVal varchar(4000) NOT NULL,
        NewVal varchar(4000) NOT NULL
    );

    RAISE NOTICE 'Task completed sucessfully.';    
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 7):

You could write this as a psql script, e.g.,

```
START TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE ...
CREATE TABLE ...
COMMIT;
\echo 'Task completed sucessfully.'
```

and run with

```
psql -f somefile.sql
```

Raising errors with parameters isn't possible in PostgreSQL directly.  When porting such code, some people encode the necessary information in the error string and parse it out if necessary.

It all works a bit differently, so be prepared to relearn/rethink/rewrite a lot of things.

Answer (score -2):

Just want to add my two cents on this old post:

In my opinion, almost all of relational database engines include a commit transaction execution automatically after execute a DDL command even when you have autocommit=false, So you don't need to start a transaction to avoid a potential truncated object creation because It is completely unnecessary.

Comment: This is wrong for Postgres. DDL is transactional the same way an UPDATE statement is.

Comment: Not True for Db2 and sql server as well so almost all may be a bit misleading.

Comment: I think this is false for Oracle and Sybase, as well as the database engines that other commentators have mentioned.  I'm wondering what you mean by "almost all", when Postgres, Oracle, Sybase, SQL Server and DB2 are all excluded.